# set a specific packet format ...java

Tags: java, packet

I want to create a chat application,
so I need to create a specific packet format .

for example)

lets consider that `pkt` is the structure

```
pkt {
    type_no;
    msg;
    dest_ID;
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Is it a good way to create a packet class and send the whole object? 
like:

```
public class Packet implements Serializable  {
    private static final long serialVersionUID  = 1L;
    private int type;
    private String data1;
    private String data2;
    private String clientID;
    private String destID;
    private boolean hasFile=false;
    private boolean hasList;
    private byte[] file ;
    private HashMap <String,String> onlineList = new HashMap<>();
.
.
.
.
.
```

Or there is a better way to handle this?

Thanx

Comment: That very much depends on many different aspects. Your question is way too generic. We can help with specific programming questions; but not with "how should I design core aspects of my application".

Comment: Well, I asked simple question to get simple answer (not lecture!). I didn't ask you to give me the program design.. I asked for the approach of creating packet format

Comment: Sure. But also simple questions do sometimes not match the "scope" of stackoverflow; as defined in the help center. I am not trying to lecture; I am just explaining to you that questions as this most often only lead to loss of reputation; rarely to increase of knowledge.

Comment: if you had the answer, then I am very sure that it would be way less of what you wrote till know

Comment: If you have a look into the help center and read about the policies of this site, then you too, would probably stop complaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method for sending class via socket

for example:

```
public class packet implements Serializable  {


    String msg;
    int no;
    int Id;
    String info;

}
```

create new object

```
packet pkt = new packet();
pkt.msg="HI";
pkt.Id=2;
.
.
.
```

For sending use

```
// simple code 
ObjectOutputStream outputStream;
outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());   
outputStream.writeObject(pkt);
socket.close();
```

For receiving use

```
// simple code 
ObjectInputStream inStream;
inStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
packet rcvPkt = (packet)inStream.readObject(); 
socket.close();
```

you will have the information in rcvPkt.
I hope that this answer helps.